# aws Unknown runtime version named 'openjdk8' of java. This build image has the following versions: corretto11, corretto8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my java application to aws EBS using codecommit

but I am faced with this error

```
YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named 'openjdk8' of java. This build image has the following versions: corretto11, corretto8
```

I am using ubuntu with codebuild standard:4.0

my runtime version in my buildspec is openjdk8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see OpenJDK listed as a supported runtime for Elastic Beanstalk [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.javase). You need to change your settings to specify `corretto8`.

Comment: But I am not using amazon linux I am using ubuntu

Comment: Please show me where in the documentation Ubuntu and OpenJDK are supported in Elastic Beanstalk? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux.html#platforms-linux.versions